# Ansible - nested loop over object without knowing object/key name

Tags: json, ansible, jmespath, json-query

I'm working on an ansible playbook, I need to get a value from a JSON API result.
I want to get the value of the key "1h" without knowing the previous object (sd#eureka...), and i need to loops over all my results, and all my buckets.

```
{
  "etat_ms_rep": {
    "results": [
      {
          "buckets": {
            "sd#eureka#pixidanalyticsbackend#c3fb422bb36882d9f502092fd75fcb34": {
              "1h": -1,
              "1m": -1
            },
            "sd#eureka#pixidanalyticsbackend#348fdab155904e22ca0c744d0c052cf8": {
              "1h": 100,
              "1m": 100
            }
          }
      },
      {
          "buckets": {
            "sd#eureka#pixidorchestratorbackend#8fa3441c6c5caa2d5f0e3264a00be91b": {
              "1h": 100,
              "1m": 100
            },
            "sd#eureka#pixidorchestratorbackend#6dc48be83cb86ae1a73b344e9421ed8e": {
              "1h": 100,
              "1m": 100
            }
          }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I tried that but without success, it doesnt show the value of "1h" key...

```
 - name: Display all bucket info
    set_fact:
     test: "{{ etat_ms_rep.results | json_query(jmesquery) }}"
    vars:
      jmesquery: " [*].['1h'] "
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- For example,

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ etat_ms_rep.results | json_query(query) }}"
      vars:
        query: '[].*.*."1h"'
```

gives

```yaml
  msg:
  - - - -1
    - - 100
  - - - 100
    - - 100
```

- Flatten the list if you want to

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ etat_ms_rep.results | json_query(query) | flatten }}"
      vars:
        query: '[].*.*."1h"'
```

gives

```yaml
  msg:
  - -1
  - 100
  - 100
  - 100
```

- It's possible to flatten the list in the pipe. The below query gives the same result

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ etat_ms_rep.results | json_query(query) }}"
      vars:
        query: '[].*.*."1h"|[]|[]'
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    etat_ms_rep:
      results:
        - buckets:
            cb34: {1h: -1, 1m: -1}
            2cf8: {1h: 100, 1m: 100}
        - buckets:
            ed8e: {1h: 100, 1m: 100}
            e91b: {1h: 100, 1m: 100}

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ etat_ms_rep.results | json_query(query) }}"
      vars:
        query: '[].*.*."1h"'

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ etat_ms_rep.results | json_query(query) | flatten }}"
      vars:
        query: '[].*.*."1h"'

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ etat_ms_rep.results | json_query(query) }}"
      vars:
        query: '[].*.*."1h"|[]|[]'
```